# How plot new point in ggplot with older color data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I know similar questions asked before but my question is different. Consider data points `data1` that have colors with respect to x and y coordinates and I plot it with `ggplot`

```
x = 1:100
y = 1:100
d = expand.grid(x,y)

data1 <- data.frame(
xval = d$Var1, 
yval = d$Var2, 
col = d$Var1+d$Var2) 

data2 <- data.frame(
xnew = c(1.5, 90.5), 
ynew = c(95.5, 4))

ggplot(data1, aes(xval, yval, colour = col)) + geom_point()
```

[image: data1]

But I want the last line don't plot anything and I want plot `data2` points with respect to colors of `data1`. for example I paint what I want to plot for `data2` :

[image: data2]

I changed the last line to:

```
ggplot(data1, aes(xval, yval, colour = col)) +
geom_point(data = data2, aes(x = xnew, y = ynew))
```

Now I expect that `ggplot` draw just 2 points of `data2`, but I have an Error:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
>   Error: Column `colour` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that there is no mapping between col out of data1 and your data2.

Please try the following:

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x = xnew, y = ynew, colour = xnew)) + geom_point() + 
scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c(2,1),
                   values   = range(data1$xval),
                   rescaler = function(x,...) x,
                   oob      = identity)
```

[image]

Comment: This code doesn't work. Consider my coordinate be (x = 8.5 , y = 90.3)

Comment: The same colors that draw in line `ggplot(data1, aes(xval, yval, colour = col)) + geom_point()`

Comment: It seems that `geom_point()` must be deleted, because of I say that I want to don't draw anything on `data1`

Comment: @mohammad I don't understand your logic behind choosing your colour by `1:nrow(d)`
I think it is just an example. So should your colours be dependend on x or y? vbecause now it just depends on the index of data1

Comment: I just produce numbers that values of this numbers determine brightness of `colour` in `ggplot`. you can produce another colors. It doesn't matter. but It's Important that length of colors must be the same as `length(xval)` or `length(yval)`

Comment: Yes this is just an example.

Comment: Yes, but is it possible instead of length to choose colours by range of y or x?

Comment: Yes but I want colors be continuous with respect to `col` value

Comment: Then you have to map your data2 to col of data1 and I don't know what's your idea behind. So maybe the functions around `scale_colour_gradient()` is usefull.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing what is being asked for. You want to plot the points for data2, but use data1 for the color scale? But what points in data1? Or do you want each point to be multicolored? Each point colored from opposite ends of the color scale? Can you draw an example in `mspaint` or something?

Comment: Answer of your first question is yes. I edited my post. I hope you get what I want.

Comment: See the edited answer above. I think it's that what you are looking for.